# Joining two lists of records and calculating a result

Tags: f#

I have two lists of records with the following types:

```
type AverageTempType = {Date: System.DateTime; Year: int64; Month: int64; AverageTemp: float}
type DailyTempType = {Date: System.DateTime; Year: int64; Month: int64; Day: int64; DailyTemp: float}
```

I want to get a new list which is made up of the DailyTempType "joined" with the AverageTempType. Ultimately though for each daily record I want the Daily Temp - Average temp for the matching month.

I think I can do this with loops as per below and massage this into a reasonable output:

```
let MatchLoop = 
    for i in DailyData do
        for j in AverageData do
                if (i.Year = j.Year && i.Month = j.Month) 
                then printfn "%A %A %A %A %A" i.Year i.Month i.Day i.DailyTemp j.Average
                else printfn "NOMATCH"
```

I have also try to do this with matching but I can't quite get there (I'm not sure how to define the list correctly in the input type and then iterate to get a result. Also I'm not sure sure if this approach even makes sense):

```
let MatchPattern (x:DailyTempType) (y:AverageTempType) = 
match (x,y) with
|(x,y) when (x.Year = y.Year && x.Month = y.Month) -> 
    printfn "match"
|(_,_) -> printfn "nomatch"
```

I have looked into Deedle which I think can do this relatively easily but I am keen to understand how to do it a lower level.

Comment: Are the lists sorted? If you want to do something at low level that's important to know.

Comment: I can have them sorted by the keys I want to match on.

Comment: @Fusi123 You always could use [`LINQ's GroupJoin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), or just research how it's implemented and how it can give a functionality equivalent to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to create a **map** of the monthly average data. You can think of a map as a read-only dictionary:

```
let averageDataMap =
    averageData
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> ((x.Year, x.Month), x))
    |> Map.ofSeq
```

This particular map is a `Map<(int64 * int64), AverageTempType>`, which, in plainer words, means that the keys into the map are tuples of year and month, and the value associated with each key is an `AverageTempType` record.

This enables you to find all the matching month data, based on the daily data:

```
let matches = 
    dailyData
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> (x, averageDataMap |> Map.tryFind (x.Year, x.Month)))
```

Here, matches has the data type `seq<DailyTempType * AverageTempType option>`. Again, in plainer words, this is a sequence of tuples, where the first element of each tuple is the original daily observation, and the second element is the corresponding monthly average, if a match was found, or `None` if no matching monthly average was found.

If you want to print the values as in the OP, you can do this:

```
matches
|> Seq.map snd
|> Seq.map (function | Some _ -> "Match" | None -> "No match")
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%s")
```

This expression starts with the `matches`; then pulls out the second element of each tuple; then again maps a `Some` value to the string "Match", and a `None` value to the string "No match"; and finally prints each string.

Comment: Thanks Mark this works great. Could you please explain (or maybe a reference) of how exactly to deal with the option type? If I use Map.find instead I can use `matches |> Seq.map (fun (x,y) ->x.DailyTemp, x.DailyTemp - y.AvgTemp) |> printfn "%A" `

Comment: The option type is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233245.aspx Another good please to read about it is here: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/the-option-type

Comment: Thanks Mark, I looked at those examples. I am still struggling a bit though because all the examples seem to be trivial cases. I can't see a case where there is a sequence of options, and I can't manage to change your example because I can't "access" the original tuples. I might post another question.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert first AverageTempType seq to a Map (reducing cost of join):

```
let toMap (avg:AverageTempType seq) = avg |> Seq.groupBy(fun a -> a.Year + a.Month) |> Map.ofSeq
```

Then you can join and return an option, so consuming code can do whatever you want (print, store, error, etc.):

```
let join (avg:AverageTempType seq) (dly:DailyTempType seq) = 
    let avgMap = toMap avg
    dly |> Seq.map (fun d -> d.Year, d.Month, d.Day, d.DailyTemp, Map.tryFind (d.Year + d.Month) avgMap);;
```